# How do I solve $\int \frac{20}{(x-1)(x^2+9)}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I've been trying to solve the following integral:
$\int \frac{20}{(x-1)(x^2+9)}dx$

Sadly I'm kinda new to resolving fractional integrals and I'm not sure which method(s) I should use to solve it.

I've tried using partial fractions but I'm doing something incorrectly or maybe this method isn't the best suited for this case.

I've tried using partial fractions. Here is what I've got so far
[image]

[image]

Comment: Partial fractions is the way I would try it. Perhaps you might like to share how far you got with this method. Edit: I've now done it. It comes out quite nicely.

Comment: $\int \frac{20}{(x-1)(x^2+9)}dx=\int \frac{2x+18}{(x-1)(x^2+9)}- \frac{2x-2}{(x-1)(x^2+9)}\ dx
=\ln \frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2+9} - \int \frac2{x^2+9}dx
$

Comment: @MichaelCohen I updated the question with what I've tried so far, I think I'm doing something wrong. I'd love some feedback :)

Comment: @Quanto are these partial fractions?

Comment: You could say that; it’s not the standard one though

Comment: Thanks Quanto and Michael, seems that Oscar and Alvin helped me to get on the right track :P

Comment: To generalize, in partial fractions, the numerators of inseparable denominators must be one degree less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should resolve the integrand as below: $$\frac{20}{(x-1)\left(x^{2}+9\right)} \equiv \frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B x+C}{x^{2}+9}$$
Then $$20 \equiv A\left(x^{2}+9\right)+(B x+C)(x-1)$$
Putting $x=1$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
20=A(10) & \Rightarrow A=2 \\
(B x+C)(x-1) &=20-2\left(x^{2}+9\right) \\
&=2-2 x^{2} \\
&=-2(x+1)(x-1) \\
\therefore \quad B x+C &=-2(x+1) \\
\therefore \frac{20}{(x-1)\left(x^{2}+9\right)} &=\frac{2}{x-1}-\frac{2(x+1)}{x^{2}+9} \\
\int \frac{20}{(x-1)\left(x^{2}+9\right)} d x &=2 \int \frac{d x}{x-1}-\int \frac{2 x d x}{x^{2}+9}-2 \int \frac{d x}{x^{2}+9}
\end{aligned}
$$

Wish it helpful for you to continue!

Answer (score 3):

Give this one a whirl.
$$\frac{20}{(x-1)(x^2+9)} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+9} $$
You should find that $A=2$ and $B=C=-2$. Hence
$$ \int \frac{20}{(x-1)(x^2+9)}\mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{2}{x-1}\mathrm{d}x - \int \frac{2x}{x^2+9}\mathrm{d}x - \int \frac{2}{x^2+9}\mathrm{d}x. $$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will do now and see if I manage, I never tried doing a quadratic one and I didn't know you had to add a linear term

Answer (score 0):

You made a common mistake with partial fractions. When there is a quadratic denominator, you have to have a linear term in the numerator:

$\dfrac{20}{(x-1)(x^2+9)}=\dfrac{A}{x-1}+\dfrac{\color{blue}{Bx+C}}{x^2+9}.$

Try this and it should work. Since the numerator in the overall fraction is constant, the logarithms will combine nicely and make the antiderivative bounded as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Will try now